# Login com permissões Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, login, permissões

Tenho um sistema de login com permissões feito com o Auth do Laravel, onde existem as opções "Aluno" e "Professor" para escolher.

Por exemplo: se ele for professor, ele vai voltar com uma tela para cadastrar provas; se for aluno, irá voltar com uma tela para visualizar as mesmas. Porém, não quero que ele volte a própria tela do Laravel, gostaria de que ao cadastrar um usuário, ele setaria para página que criei à respectiva opção que o usuário escolheu.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode reescrever a função login no `LoginController`, e dentro do `if` que checa as credenciais `auth()->attempt()` você pode colocar outro `if` checando se é aluno ou professor, e retornar para o url correto.

Por exemplo:

```
return redirect()->intended('professor/dashboard');
```